# Web API Model Bind CSV inside complex type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

My ASP.NET Web API class has a GET endpoint that has a variety of filters, which are mapped to a filter class from the URI:

Controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult List([FromUri] FilterModel filter)
```

Filter class:

```
public class FilterModel {
    public int Something {get;set;}
    public int[] UserIds {get;set;}
    ...lots of other properties...
}
```

I'd like UserIds to be passed as a comma-separated list:

```
http://foo.com/api/things?UserIds=1,2,3
```

But, this being Web API, it expects:

```
http://foo.com/api/things?UserIds=1&UserIds=2&UserIds=3
```

Is there a simple way to solve this problem. I see that I can create a custom Model Binder, but for 99% of the model binding, I don't want to change anything. My ideal solution would be something like this:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {

        // Access the "default" model that's created from the Uri params
        var model = ???

        // Then do some work to bind the UserIds

        return true;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You need to create a Custom Media Type Formatter , e.g:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633402/csv-media-type-formatter-for-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, if this is too simple, but as a parameter value of "1,2,3" can (afaik) only be passed as a string, you can use `string.Split` to convert the value(s) to an array of int:

```c#
var userIds = Array.ConvertAll(parm.Split(','), int.Parse);
```

Of course, there is a chance of running into a FormatException, when not all comma-separated values are numbers, so you'ld better do the conversion with more than one line of code.

Hope it helps.